# How to connect to Azure Service Bus queue using AMQP over WebSocket on browser?

Tags: websocket, amqp, azureservicebus

I have a Node app that can connect to Azure Service Bus queue using AMQP over WebSocket. The following are the libraries that I'm using:

- node-amqp10 from noodlefrenzy
- node-amqp10-transport-ws from noodelfrenzy
- nodejs-websocket from sitegui

With the above libraries, I'm trying to make React app that will connect to Azure Service Bus queue using AMQP over WebSocket. I have made some changes to nodejs-websocket locally to replace the websocket. Below is the code that I'm using:

```
var url = 'wss://saskeyname:saskey@sbnamespace.servicebus.windows.net:443/$servicebus/websocket';
var socket = new WebSocket(url, 'AMQPWSB10');
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    console.log('onmessage:', event.data);
};
socket.onerror = function (event) {
    console.error('onerror:', event);
};
socket.onclose = function (event) {
    console.log('onclose:', event);
};
socket.onopen = function (event) {
    console.log('onopen:', event) {
    sasl.negotiate();
};
```

The web socket is closed as soon as the SASL negotiation starts.
I have the logs as below:

```
onopen: Event {isTrusted: true, type: "open", target: WebSocket, currentTarget: WebSocket, eventPhase: 2, …} Connection.js:66 
write: Uint8Array(14) [130, 136, 117, 116, 125, 158, 52, 57, 44, 206, 118, 117, 125, 158] Connection.js:102
onclose: CloseEvent {isTrusted: true, wasClean: false, code: 1000, reason: "", type: "close", …}
```

Am I doing something wrong?